# VS Code does not provide intellisense - .NET Core app

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

After an update (exactly I can not remember whether it was VS Code itself or some extension), suddenly VS Code stopped recognizing, suggesting code imports and IntelliSense for my .NET Core project.

I tried to re-install, downgrade/upgrade all necessary extensions.
i.e. C# extensions, however, nothing really changed.

The only output I get in the Output Console is "Downloading the .NET Runtime", but nothing really happens.

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Have you tried running without extensions and only enabling extensions one at a time to find the potential sinner? Quick way to disable all extensions for a session: `code --disable-extensions`

Comment: vscode is not for serious c# development, trust me, i am suffering now)

Comment: @Xerillio, I did try disabling/enabling all the extensions one at a time, but it did not help.

Comment: @Ryan I am using for almost 3 years vs code for C# development in a wide range of scopes, but this is the first time I am in the middle of nowhere waiting for some magic to happen to get this problem solved. However, you are completely right, I get problems every now and then.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am stupid. Anyway, what I did was uninstall all the .NET, C# related extensions and only install the two which was suggested by Microsoft in the following link

[Setting up VS Code for .NET development](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/dotnet)

Extensions that I installed to solve the issue.

[C# DevKit](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csdevkit)

[C#](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp)

As far as I remember, the extensions I uninstalled were the C# extensions by JosKreative (which supposedly shouldn't do anything with the problem), dotnet by leolabs, dotnet core essentials by Kishori Ithadi, .Net Core Tools by Jan Han.

Comment: If you ever subscribe to VS blog, you should have known the big changes there, https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/announcing-csharp-dev-kit-for-visual-studio-code/ Naturally, you have to reconfigure a lot.